# How to get drawable resource in android programmatically?

Tags: android, getresource

I want to get the drawable id which is shown in the screen.
I used
if(getResources().getDrwable(binding.image1)==R.drawable.image){ //my stuff}
But this is depreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use alternative of `getResources().getDrawable(int id)` as mentioned below

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context,int drawableId)
```